# what is the meaning of the expression =&var-> in clock setting function for efr32fg14 EVM

Tags: embedded

in the CMU_ClockEnable function shown bellow we have a "clock" variable shown below.

`>>` is left shift
our variable gets compared to some other variables. in the end they use an expression of
`reg = &CMU->CLKEN1`.

I know that `&` is bitwise "and".
What is the meaning of `reg = &CMU->CLKEN1`  expression in C programming?

```
void CMU_ClockEnable(CMU_Clock_TypeDef clock, bool enable)
{
  volatile uint32_t *reg = NULL;
  uint32_t          bit;

  /* Identify the enable register. */
  if (((unsigned)clock >> CMU_EN_REG_POS) == CMU_NO_EN_REG) {
    EFM_ASSERT(false);                      /* No enable for this clock. */
  } else if (((unsigned)clock >> CMU_EN_REG_POS) == CMU_CLKEN0_EN_REG) {
    reg = &CMU->CLKEN0;
  } else if (((unsigned)clock >> CMU_EN_REG_POS) == CMU_CLKEN1_EN_REG) {
    reg = &CMU->CLKEN1;
  } else {
    reg = &CMU->CRYPTOACCCLKCTRL;
  }

  /* Get the bit position used to enable/disable. */
  bit = ((unsigned)clock >> CMU_EN_BIT_POS) & CMU_EN_BIT_MASK;

  /* Set/clear bit as requested. */
  BUS_RegBitWrite(reg, bit, (uint32_t)enable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know that & is bitwise "and"

Not in this context.  The `&` *binary* operator (i.e. one with two operands left and right of the operator) is *bitwise-and*.  Here it is the *unary* operator (one operand) `&` which is the *address-of* operator and evaluates to a pointer to the operand.

In that case `reg = &CMU->CLKEN1` makes `reg` a pointer to the `CMU_CLKEN1` register.  The code sets `reg` to the enable register of the clock identified by the `clock` parameter, so that a single `BUS_RegBitWrite()` call may be used for either clock.

The code will become clearer when read in in the context of your target MCU's datasheet or reference manual.  It is directly accessing peripheral device registers on your MCU.